# Building ubuntu touch app with sql (mysql) support problem

Tags: ubuntu-touch, mysql, qt, qml

i`m trying to develop simple ubuntu application. This application should connect to remove mysql server, query and display data in UbuntuListView. Project was created in  Qt Creator 3.1.1 as QML app with c++ plugin (cmake).
In my cpp class, i connect to mysql server using:

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

according to qt documentation. On my desktop (ubuntu 14.04) application works fine (after installing libqt5sql5-mysql), but when i tried to run this application on my aquaris E4.5 ubuntu edition i got this error:

QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded

QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE

Open database:  false

I have found package libqt5sql5-mysql 5.3.0+dfsg-2ubuntu9 (armhf binary) for utopic unicorn. In qt creator, under Tools->Options->Ubuntu, I clicked on Maintain button in Framework ubuntu-sdk-14.10 and install that package. But this didn`t solve my problem.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

`libqt5sql5-mysql` is not a part of the default image.  If you wish to use it, you must either install it on the phone (which I assume would require making your image writable) or include it as part of your application.

As an example, QHttpServer is not provided by the default image.  I use it in Beru, so I build it as [part of my application](https://github.com/rschroll/beru/tree/master/qhttpserver).